# Possible jquery / library conflict in plugin usage

Tags: plugins, jquery, css, javascript, html

I am using the free version of the plugin: WP Feedback & Survey Manager

but for some reasons the tab style is not rendered, and I guess it's for a javascript/jquery problem, eventhough I don't get any console errors.

This is the plugin public url I installed:
http://www.riccardo.it/newtech/questionnaire/

And here it is how it should look like (See tabs in screenshot #4):
http://www.intechgrity.com/wp-plugins/wp-feedback-survey-manager/

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: You are getting a Javascript errors. Check the console in Chrome.

Comment: Now I don't get any javascript errors but the result does not change :S

Answer (score 0):

The gallery plugin is loading it's scripts before the jQuery migrate script which is being loaded by the jquery updater plugin

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.riccardo.it/newtech/wp-content/plugins/jquery-updater/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js?ver=2.1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.riccardo.it/newtech/wp-content/plugins/gallery-plugin/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js?ver=3.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.riccardo.it/newtech/wp-content/plugins/gallery-plugin/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=3.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.riccardo.it/newtech/wp-content/plugins/jquery-updater/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

This is causing a JavaScript error which is preventing other scripts from running.

Try disabling the jQuery updater plugin and let WordPress load jQuery correctly.

Comment: I disabled the jquery updater, I don't get any error but the result is the same... Any clue?

Comment: If you view your page source, half the page is actually commented out. It starts on line 256 and includes a number of scripts and HTML up to and including the closing body and html tags.